# Matlab: kmeans clustering gives unexpected clusters

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

Example:

```
load kmeansdata %provides X variable
Y=bsxfun(@minus,X,mean(X,2))'/sqrt(size(X,2)-1); %normalized and means adjusted
[~,~,PC] = svd(Y); %
plot(PC(:,1),PC(:,2),'m.','markersize',15)
```

plot the first two columns and you will get what looks like 3 clusters. I want to identify these clusters using kmeans, and plot the clusters in different colours as prood. I tried:

```
[idx,cntrd] = kmeans(PC(:,1:2),3,'Distance','sqEuclidean');%,'Distance','correlation');

cluster=3;
Col = {'.b','.r','.g','.y','.m','.c','.k'}; % Cell array of colours.
figure;
hold on
for clus=1:cluster
  plot(PC(idx==clus,1),PC(idx==clus,2),Col{clus},'MarkerSize',12)  
end
plot(cntrd(:,1),cntrd(:,2),'kx','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3) %plotting the centroids of the clusters
```

The cluster centroids are off, and the colours aren't what I expected either. Can anyone help?

## EDIT: Somewhat answered:

I copied this code from the mathworks site and replaced my kmeans line:

```
opts = statset('Display','final');
[idx,C] = kmeans(PC(:,1:2),3,'Distance','cityblock',...
    'Replicates',5,'Options',opts);
```

it seems to work, but I don't quite understand what opts does. Replicates, I assume, just repeats kmeans 5 times, and picks some kind of average for the centroids. I've also restarted matlab in case there was some sort of glitch

## EDIT: ignore above:

I thought the problem was resolved, so then I tried looking into finding appropriate k values. I entered k=1, ran everything, then k=2, then k=3 and I noticed I got the same mistake again

Comment: First suggestion (just a side note really) is that you can easily plot the groups as different colours using [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html). And secondly, have you tried using the `'Replicates',5` option but sticking with the default Euclidean distance rather than the using `cityblock`? Also try leaving off the `opts` part, maybe you don't need it...

Comment: look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/statset.html  for what `opts` is doing. It seems like the `Display` property only affects the console output of your function, i.e. what feedback it gives you. btw I think you are right re `replicate`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#bueftl4-1

Comment: @Dan I ran the code that was shown in my first "EDIT: Somewhat answered:" section (which included the cityblock parameter, and it no longer works as expected. I ran the code again without the distance/cityblock pair so that it uses the default and i still no longer works as expected.

In both cases, the centroids are wrong (two of them are in the middle cluster, the third one looks correct), and the colour scheme for both is wrong (the top half of the left and middle clusters are red, the bottoms are blue, although the right cluster seems correctly coloured green).

Comment: Did you try increasing the replicate parameter number larger than 5?

Comment: @Dan I changed replicates to 10 (again no distance name/pair), and it is worse. Before at least the last (right side) cluster had a correct centroid and coloured in everyhing green, now all 3 clusters are wrong.

Would pictures help?

Comment: In taking photos of changing repetitions and repetitions/distance namepair, it seems that using cityblock works now, whether for 5 reps or 10.

I'm not quite sure why it didn't work before. If I run the code using city block and 5 repetitions many times, will I ALWAYS get the same result? or did I accidentally make a mistake when running

Comment: Without seeing what you see, it's hard to tell what is wrong on your picture.

Answer (score 0):

kmeans can be sensitive to the initial centroid locations. The trouble seems to be the algorithm used for selecting the starting points. for example, you can get the expected answer by running this:

```
[idx,cntrd] = kmeans(PC(:,1:2),3, 'start', [-0.05 0; 0 0; 0.05  0]);
```

Looks can also be deceiving. In this case the dispersion of the data is not equal in the x and y dimensions. Thus, for some pairs of points, the euclidean distance is not as far between the visual clusters as it is within clusters.

You might consider using a mixture of Guassian distributions model for this data.